# using sql like in java

Tags: java, sql

I make a procedure that get a nvarchar and it return a table by using like and it works well. but when I want to use this procedure in java it doesn't work.
here is the java code.

```
  String query = "exec Predict ?";
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  pst.setString(1, "%"+"ee"+"%");

  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  int i = 0;
  while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    i++;
   }
```

Comment: Why do you think, this code didn't work?

Comment: because it doesn't return anything when i sysout it

Answer (score 0):

Hey you actually can't just call it as a query. You got to make it a callable statement and execute it. This is the code I have been using. It takes in parameters too, but if you dont need that, just remove it. This is sort of customized for my project setup, but this will help you out:

```
/** 
     * This method takes in a stored procedure along with its parameters and parameter type and creates a result set from them.
     * @param storedProcedure
     * @param parameters
     * @param parameterType
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static ResultSet createRSFromStoredProc(String storedProcedure, ArrayList<String> parameters, ArrayList<String> parameterType) throws SQLException {

        // Initializes variables that are used in the method.
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        // Builds the stored procedure calling
        String insertStoreProc = "{call " + storedProcedure + "(";
        for(int i=0;i<parameters.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i==parameters.size()-1)
                insertStoreProc+="?";
            else
                insertStoreProc+="?,";
        }
        insertStoreProc+=")}";


        try {
            // establishes the connection
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();

            // creates the callable statement
            callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(insertStoreProc);

            // Parses the string into the correct parameter type and sets the parameter to the value.
            for(int i=0;i<parameters.size(); i++)
            {
                if(parameterType.get(i).equals("string"))
                    callableStatement.setString(i+1, parameters.get(i));
                else if(parameterType.get(i).equals("int"))
                    callableStatement.setInt(i+1, Integer.parseInt(parameters.get(i)));
                if(parameterType.get(i).equals("dateTime"))
                {
                    // if now is entered for the time gets the current timestamp
                    if(parameters.get(i).equals("now"))
                        callableStatement.setTimestamp(i+1, Timestamp.valueOf(getCurrentDate()));
                    else
                    {
                        callableStatement.setString(i+1, parameters.get(i));
                    }

                }   
            }

            // execute insertDBUSER store procedure
            Boolean results = callableStatement.execute();
            int rowsAffected=0;
            while(results||rowsAffected!=-1)
            {
                if(results)
                {
                    rs=callableStatement.getResultSet();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    rowsAffected=callableStatement.getUpdateCount();
                }
                results= callableStatement.getMoreResults();
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } 
        return rs;

    }
```